# jdbc : postgres and quoted column names

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

Is there any way to determine in JDBC that a column or table has been created using "" notation? The metadata get columns does not seem to return such information.

PS: our customer model has been unfortunately created in such a way :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column name is returned in mixed case or all upper then it has been created using quotes.

So if `columnName.equals(columnName.toLowerCase()) == true` then no quotes were used. Or to be more prices: no quotes are needed.

Note that this is Postgres specific. Other databases store unquoted names in uppercase, some store them "as-is" without requiring quotes.

Comment: +1 especially for including _"Or to be more prices: no quotes are needed"_ case.